# Mathbbold in Beamer

Tags: beamer, blackboard

I am trying to write a beamer presentation, but I can't use the `bbold` package. Here is the code I wrote:

```
\documentclass[pdf]
{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\makeatletter
%% preamble

\usepackage{bbold}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbold}{bbold}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
$\mathbbold{0}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
! Font U/bbold/m/n/10.95=bbold11 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.16 \end{frame}
```

Do you have any idea about how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** After adding `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}`, I got the error messages which can be found [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=20112260728824196757).

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me. Can you please post the output of `\listfiles`?

Comment: I think you mean the `bbold` package, not `mathbbold`. I can compile the document above, but I get a warning about missing shape

Comment: @Benjamin, How can I do that? Maybe I don't have the proper font, which font should I look for?

Comment: Just add `\listfiles` at the beginning of your document. Then you will get a list of all packages and their versions in the log file (beginning with `*File List*`)

Comment: @Benjamin, I added a link to the output I got.

Comment: You should add `\listfiles` even before `\documentclass`. By the way, you should definitely remove the `\makeatletter` macro. It does not make any sense here and can easily produce errors.

Comment: @Benjamin I tried to move the `\listfiles` to the top and deleted the `\makeatletter`, but it still doesn't show me anything with `*File List*`... Any other idea?

Comment: Your MWE compiles fine for me. Can you please state which tex distribution you are using? And which operating system?

Comment: Try to blow away the temp files and recompile. If that does not help, and you are using MikTex, update and rebuild everything through the maintenance tool.